# avahi slow to start - can ping IP, but hostname comes online after few mintues

Tags: avahi

I've a strange problem.

On ubuntu server 11. I've avahi running.

When I restart machine, in about 1 min server is up, I can connect through SSH or ping it via IP. But not via hostname server.local - it takes about 3-4 minutes for server.local to become accessible. That's allot!

I installed avahi to handle hostname. I believe there is something wrong with startup procedure and it gets delayed or smth. How should I diagnose the problem? or is there way to configure avahi to be more responsive?

p.s. I also noticed few times, hostname was accessible but not IP. Which makes me believe there is something really wrong going on.

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed problem by disabling ipv6 in avahi settings file. It was in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`

Answer (score 0):

try to edit /etc/nsswitch.conf

I had the same issue, and i disabled mdns, so if you have:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

try  to replace with:

```
hosts:      files dns
```